# expect command hangs at different stages of script

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, redhat, expect

I have an automation script that installs a new image "flash.sh", I am trying to run the flash script from a geographically different location, when i use "expect" command to call the script script it hangs unexpectedly at different stages in the script at different runs.. 
The call is ..

```
 expect -c 'set timeout 1800;exp_internal 1;match_max 10000;spawn ssh root@client "sh /tmp/flash.sh 'root@server:/loc/test.sdcard'";expect "*?assword:"; send "pass\r"; interact'
```

script flash.sh , is creating mount , using pivot_root, moving mounts and in the end using

```
dd if=./$IMAGE_FILENAME of=/dev/mmc.. bs=1M
```

I have tried adding debug and adding sleep to the remote script , but still same behavior. after pressing cntrl+c

```
    Killed by signal 2.
interact: received eof from spawn_id exp6
tty_set: raw = 0, echo = 1
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -c  argv[2] = set timeout 1800;exp_internal 1;match_max 10000;spawn ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx  "sh /tmp/sw_flash.sh root:/loc/test.sdcard";expect "*?assword:"; send "pass\r"; interact
set argc 0
set argv0 "expect"
set argv ""
tty_set: raw = 5, echo = 0
```

I also used the debug mode but no error or does not timeout .
PS : when i run the same script on a machine at same geo location , all commands pass as expected.

Please help .. been struggling for few days now

Edit 1:
Adding the verbose as suggested and changed the interact to expect EOF , i had to kill with Cntrl + C

```
 expect: does " \r\nunmounting /mnt/net and recreating this directory\r\numount: /mnt/net: mountpoint not found\r\nprovided path is not mounted\r\ncreating /mnt/net was successful\r\nstopping services\r\nCan't find /test/service/main.pyc! Using /test/service/main.py instead.\r\nStopping Service: /usr/bin/python3 /test/service/main.py\r\nSUCCESSFULLY STOPPED\r\nmounting remote rootfs from test@server:/test/images/latest at /mnt/net\r\nsshfs mount command was successful\r\nwaiting for 120 seconds for the system to be ready for rootfs change in case it is not\r\nchanging rootfs to ./mnt/net/oldroot\r\nwaiting for 120 seconds for the system to be ready for rootfs change in case it is not\r\n" (spawn_id exp6) match glob pattern "EOF"? no
^Csighandler: handling signal(2)
async event handler: Tcl_Eval(exit 130)
```

Comment: "Hanging" generally indicates one of your expect patterns has not matched, and you are waiting for the `timeout` period to end before the `expect` command gives up and your script continues. Read through the verbose debugging output to see how your patterns are or are not matching.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i changed the ' interact' in the call , to expect EOF and it worked for the first time, but rerunning the same command got stuck again at one of the commands.. i got the verbose for both the passed and failed commands , but saw nothing unusual ,

Comment: @glennjackman - any inputs or things i can try ? since there are instances when the script runs and some not . is there any buffers i can clear or insert wait/sleep ? the script takes around 30 mins to run ..

Comment: It's `expect eof` - lower case

Comment: @glenn Jackman Thanks again for your time.i can try with lower cases .yesterday I tried to execute to the very minimal ..like dissecting the command one by one. And ran just the ssh command. Without expect. And it still hangs ..tried variety of things. Like clientalivei terval, serveralive interval and Max count ,checking the MTU,using 1>&2 in the command ..but still it sometimes hangs and sometimes runs.my script is on a machine (tmp)where I am executing mount ,will that cause the server to not read the file ? After pivot ? I have posted another question maybe I can link it here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54364557/moving-to-new-root-directory-after-pivot-root-hangs